# How read out the byte stream data of a SourceBuffer/MediaSource object?

Tags: javascript

Now that I'm tweaking the `MediaSource` objects in JS, I find there seems to be no way to directly read out the byte stream data appended to SourceBuffer (i.e. a `readBuffer()` API). Is it true or I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same problem like mine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543595/get-a-stream-of-bytes-from-navigator-mediadevices-getusermedia/51544362#51544362

Comment: @Dachstein thanks! I'm no longer working on this approach and have switched to another methodology, but still... Didn't know this interface at all.